# Can we have $(a \wedge b) \to c$ but not $a \to c$ or $b \to c$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I could like to know can we have:

- $a \not \to c$
- $b \not \to c$
- however $(a \wedge b) \to c$

what is a logic table fitting that criterion?  In general:

- $a_k \not \to c$ for any $k = 1, 2, \dots, n$
- yet we observe: $(a_1 \wedge \dots \wedge a_n) \to c$

Comment: What do you mean by $\not \implies$ ?  For example, suppose $a$ is $x \text{ is divisible by 2}$ and $b$ is $x \text { is divisible by 3}$ and $c$ is $x \text{ is divisible by 6}$.  Then $c$ does not follow from $a$, but also it is not provable that $\lnot (a \implies c)$.

Comment: @DanielV that is very interesting, for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $x \equiv 0 \mod 2$ about $\frac{1}{2}$ the time, $x \equiv 0 \mod 3$ about $\frac{1}{3}$ the time, and $x \equiv 0 \mod 6$ about $\frac{1}{6}$ the time (with small error, that you sometimes notice).  However if you fix any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ the truth table merely reads:
$$ \begin{array}{cc|c}
a & b & c \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1
 \end{array} $$
for the statement $(a \wedge b) \to c$.

Comment: Did I write the truth table correctly?

Comment: It seems this can happen in general where there are multiple prerequisites for finishing a task. An example is we have a multiple source files and we need to compile them and link them against some libraries to produce an executable binary. While the source files and libraries taken individually are not enough to produce the executable, when all of them are combined, it is possible.

Comment: @cactus314 I think you did not write the truth table "correctly".  The truth table depends on the value of $x$, and $(a \land b) \implies c$ should always be true for any given $x$.

Comment: @cactus314 And the truth table you wrote is for $c = a \text{ xnor } b$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, consider "I have my username" = a and "I have my password" = b. Then let c = "I can logon to my account."

More generally this can occur quite easily as well, trivially you could have a vector of $n$ entries and let $a_n$ = "The nth letter is [letter here]" and c = "the vector is equal to [vector here]."

Comment: Nice example with the login.

Comment: @JohnColeman glad you like it. I thought an nice concrete one from real life would lighten the mood given that the case of $n$ things is necessarily more math-structured. :)

Answer (score 0):

No.  I'll try to work this out to show to show via a truth-table (with the help of [wolfram alpha)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5BNOT+(A+AND+B)+OR+C%5D+AND+NOT(NOT+A+OR+C)+AND+NOT(NOT+B+OR+C)) that 
the conjunction of all three following propositions cannot hold true, simultaneously:

$$(A\land B) \rightarrow C \equiv \lnot(A\land B) \lor C\tag 1$$

$$\lnot (B\rightarrow C) \equiv \lnot (\lnot B \lor C)\tag 2$$
$$\lnot (A\rightarrow C) \equiv \lnot (\lnot B \lor C)\tag 3$$

[image]

So $(A\land B)\rightarrow C$ cannot hold true given ($\lnot (A\rightarrow C)$ and $\lnot (B\rightarrow C).$)

Answer (score 0):

You’re asking if $(a\land b)\to c$ and $\lnot(a\to c)\land\lnot(b\to c)$ can both be true at the same time. Let’s rewrite the first formula: $$\begin{align}(a\land b)\to c &\equiv \lnot(a\land b)\lor c \\ &\equiv \lnot a\lor\lnot b\lor c \\ &\equiv (\lnot a\lor c)\lor(\lnot b\lor c) \\ &\equiv (a\to c)\lor(b\to c).\end{align}$$ That last formula is the negation of $\lnot(a\to c)\land\lnot(b\to c)$, so the latter clearly can’t be true when $(a\land b)\to c$ is. Indeed, we can see directly from the last equivalence that if the first implication is true, then at least one of the individual implications must be as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends... From a propositional logic point of view, if 'a', 'b' and 'c' are simple propositions, it is not possible; however, if 'a', 'b', and 'c' are not necessarily simple, then it could be the case that 'a' = p → q, 'b' = p, and 'c' = q. In this case, it´s correct to say that ¬(a→c)∧¬(b→c) and (a∧b)→c.

Moreover, from a predicate logic point of view, it is obviously true (in some cases). For example: ¬(∀x (Px → Qx) → Qa) and ¬(Pa→Qa) but (∀x (Px → Qx)∧ Pa)→Qa.